# How to get to the property window in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I need to lower my XNA graphics so my laptop can run it, I don't understand how to do it, I decided to try it due this link, but I don't know how to get the properties window https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4262/error-on-new-xna-4-0-game-project-no-suitable-graphics-card-found
In that Link you can see the properties window that I'm talking about. 
Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682111/how-to-change-properties-in-xnadisplay-properties-etc).

Answer (score 0):

go to project menu, select [[project name]] properties, its the first tab

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straight forward go to "Project" near the bottom select " 'Your Project Name' Properties".